# is there any other way to load data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am new to data science and Python programming. I am having trouble loading a csv file in a jupyter notebook.

This is for Windows 10. I have already tried restarting the kernel and clearing the output.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C/users/SHIVAM/desktop/brazil.csv.csv")
```

I expected the dataset to be loaded in jupyter notebook. It also raises file not found error.

Comment: Can you try with `data = pd.read_csv("C:\users\SHIVAM\Desktop\brazil.csv")`? I think it's your path formatting that's at fault here.

Comment: my first question please ignore grammatical or other errors

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different separator (`\`) for windows paths and they should be escaped properly with a double-slash (`\\`). You're also missing a colon in `C:`

You path should look like this: `'C:\\users\\SHIVAM\\desktop\\brazil.csv.csv'` or using your code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\users\\SHIVAM\\desktop\\brazil.csv.csv')
```

All of this assumes that this path is really the correct path you want and the file is actually there, you should make sure that it does.

Some of these different path separator problems can be fixed if you use something like `pathlib` which is intended to be cross platform:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('C:/users/SHIVAM/desktop/brazil.csv.csv')
>>> p
WindowsPath('C:/users/SHIVAM/desktop/brazil.csv.csv')
>>> str(p)
'C:\\users\\SHIVAM\\desktop\\brazil.csv.csv'
```

Comment: Or, use `r'...'` to avoid the need to escape the `\\`.

Comment: @SethMMorton that's true only if the \ isn't at the end of the path (try doing `path = r'C:\'`) and it also doesn't fix the problem of confusing between the slashes

Comment: That's true. But that's not the case here.  It may not fix the confusion problem, but it makes it easier to type/read with backslashes.

Comment: @SethMMorton you're not wrong, using the `r'...'` is mostly what I do, just wanted to point that out for clarity